# Non convergent subsequence in complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a *complete* metric space and $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence, that has no convergent subsequences. I have to prove, that there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\epsilon >0 $ s.t. $d(x_{n_k}, x_{n_l}) \geq \epsilon$ for all $k \neq l$.

Edit:

Contraposition would be a possible way to prove it as said in the comments, but I am stuck. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Notice that for $x_n=(-1)^n$ and $\epsilon=1$ your condition is satisfied by setting $l_M=M$ and $k_{M,l}=M+1$, but of course you are not quite so close to devising a strictly increasing function $g_\epsilon:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that, for all $t$ and $s$, either $t=s$ or $d(x_{g_\epsilon(t)},x_{g_\epsilon(s)})\ge1$.

Comment: In your case, $x_n = (-1)^n$ would have convergent subsequences, so that my assumption, that $x_n$ has no convergent subsequence would not hold. Maybe I misunderstood your comment, and you can elaborate.

Comment: My point stands, but the example is wrong. Take $x_n=3n+(-1)^n$ instead.

Comment: Thank you. What is the flaw in my argumentation? I am not sure, I understand the problem exactly.

Comment: The problem is that you think that you have defined a sequence just because you have written $x_k$ and $x_l$ somewhere.

Comment: I see. Now I am not sure, what exactly to do. I have to prove the existence of such a subsequence and constant for an arbitrary $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ wrt to the given conditions.

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive: That if for every subsequence and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $k\ne l$ with $d(x_{n_k}, x_{n_l}) < \epsilon$, then $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I tried it via contraposition in the meanwhile too, but I am clueless...